# kubernetes : How to deploy two react-js applications in the same domain, where the first is in the root and other is in a specific path

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

Since 3 days, I have a problem with a deployment in kubernetes. I would like to deploy two react-js application : the first in http://app.my-domain.com and the other in http://app.my-domain.com/shop

NB: the two url is fake, it's just for example.

The first react application was very well deployed in http://app.my-domain.com . Now when i want to put the second react application in http://app.my-domain.com/shop, it's not working.

NB: The two react applications are in different namespaces and exposed with two ingress configurations.

Here are my two ingress configuration which expose my clusterIP services relative to the two react-js applications
:

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: app.my-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: first-service
              servicePort: 80

spec:
  rules:
    - host: app.my-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /shop
            backend:
              serviceName: second-service
              servicePort: 80
```

So I have a blank page with the second application.

Please I would like your help for deploying this two react-js applications in this same domain.

Comment: It's a lot easier if you just redirect 302 from your first app, and that is the right way to do.

Comment: I don't understand : redirect 302 from the first app in react-js ? PLease could you explain ?

Comment: Are your `first-service` and `second-service` Services in the same Namespaces as your Ingress resources ?
Maybe you need to use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` annotation in your second Ingress resource ?

Comment: @matt_j, all about my first application (deployment, service, ingress, configmap) is in a specific namespace and all about my second application (deployment, service, ingress, configmap) is in another namespace.
OK thank you, i will try rewrite-target annotation.

Comment: any progress ?
Does this comment answer your question or do you still have this problem ?

Comment: No it didn't work for me.

Comment: can you add the solution that worked for you? I have 2 react app in same namespace and need to deploy them.

Comment: hello @mukesh.kumar, in the same namespace, there is no problem. You can only use one ingress resource for both services : it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple solution for this, is to use one ingress resource with this domain (app.my-domain.com) and reference the two services with their fqdn : first-service.my-namespace-1.svc.cluster.local, second-service.my-namespace-2.svc.cluster.local.

I am very interested in another solution.